# Simple assignment coming up with wrong value

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

```
private static void convert(int x) {
    // assume we've passed in x=640.

    final int y = (x + 64 + 127) & (~127);
    // as expected, y = 768

    final int c = y;
    // c is now 320?!
}
```

Are there any sane explanations for why the above code would produce the values above? This method is called from JNI. The `x` that is passed in is originally a C++ `int` type that is `static_cast` to a `jint` like so: `static_cast<jint>(x);`

In the debugger, with the breakpoint set on the y assignment, I see x=640. Stepping one line, I see y=768. Stepping another line and c=320. Using the debugger, I can set the variable c = y and it will correctly assign it 768.

This code is single threaded and runs many times per second and the same result is always observed.

**Update from comments below**

This problem has now disappeared entirely after a day of debugging it. I'd blame it on cosmic rays if it didn't happen reproducibly for an entire day. Oddest thing I've seen in a very long time.

I'll leave this question open for a while in case someone has some insight on what could possibly cause this.

Comment: Did you translate the c++ part with `-O0`?

Comment: The debugger can lie to you. Log the values and see what you get.

Comment: @user2708138, the C++ code is currently compiled with -O0 (more precisely, we don't pass in a -O value and -O0 is the default.)

Comment: @AlanStokes, the code in question does something useful with the value of `c` and it indeed is using 320 as the value and coming up with a horribly wrong answer. When I set a breakpoint after the assignment of `c` and force it to 768, it comes up with the right answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `final`? I am not a java programmer but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html gives the impression that the final could be misplaced here. But, there I am just guessing...

Comment: @user2708138, `final` here means that I won't be changing the value of that variable after its initial value. Thanks for your suggestions on things to try to fix the issue. However, I can work around this issue by simply using `y` further down in this method to perform the additional work. What I'm specifically looking for here in this question is any sane explanation for what could cause this issue. I have never personally seen anything like this and am stumped as to why it is happening.

Comment: Is it possible that Java is trying to optimize out `c` because it's redundant?

Comment: I have taken the code above, added a `System.out.println(c);`, stuck it in a java class, compiled it to a class file, make a C++ program that creates a JVM (version 1.6), looks up the class and method, and then calls `env->CallStaticVoidMethod(class, method, static_cast<jint>(640));` which produces 768.  I don't see where the 320 comes from...   Does it work if you execute the function from a java test program without JNI?

Comment: It has to be some insidious corruption from the other side of the JNI - but extremely odd that it can cause such an effect, and be repeatable.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, thanks for trying to isolate this issue. I'll do the same on the platform where I see this issue which is an S4 running Android 4.3 with native code compiled to the armeabi-v7a architecture.

Comment: Were you debugging the application in debug or release? Sometimes debugging in release will give some unwanted results that are false because of the build settings.

Comment: @AlanStokes, I think you're right as I can't seem to get this to reproduce in a stripped down environment on the target platform. There's got to be something that is odd with the `int` that is passed in. In fact, this problem has now disappeared entirely after a day of debugging it. I'd blame it on cosmic rays if it didn't happen reproducibly for an entire day. Oddest thing I've seen in a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Step 01: compile it right, see comments under your post.

if needed i with this code it will go:
C# Code:

```
private void callConvert(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myString = Convert.ToString(convert123(640));
            textBox1.Text = myString;
        }
    private static int convert123(int x) {
    // assume we've passed in x=640.
    int y = (x + 64 + 127) & (~127);
    // as expected, y = 768
    int c = y;
    // c is now 320?!
    return (c);
}
```

but its a c# code

and a tipp for you NEVER call your funktion with a name that is used in the compiler as an standart.
 convert is in the most langues used.

```
(system.convert)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked -- I'm looking for an explanation that could possibly explain the behavior seen, not working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set c to 320 recently? If so, it may have been stored in some memory and the compiler may have reassigned it to what it thought it was and not what it should be. I am, in part, guessing though.

Comment: In this code, `c` is always assigned to `y` -- never to anything else. The only thing interesting to me about `c` being 320 is that it is half of `x`, but I couldn't find a connection between those two other than that.

Comment: I'm surprised, could it have been the compiler to blame some how? Otherwise I have no idea what happened. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like problem of memory byte size of temporary variables if program is optimized for memory usage. Debugger may not be reliable. I see if the temporary ~127 is store in a byte, then you may reach at the scenario you observed. It all depends on what is ~127 is stored in at run time.